# How to transform a SoapObject in a legible data?

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I`m trying something like this:

```
envelope.implicitTypes = true;
SoapObject listaDataSet = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
   for (int i = 0; i < listaDataSet.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

   SoapObject obj = (SoapObject) listaDataSet.getProperty(i);

   // ArrayList<String>
   listaDeResultados.add(obj.toString());
}
```

But the result is a disorganized data. And i`m need something like this:
Id: -- Name: -- Descripition: --

This is the disorganized data: (Is a .dot dataset) anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; diffgram=anyType{NewDataSet=anyType{Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=401; USUARIO_NOME=tc3; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T13:37:19.89-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T13:37:19.89-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=402; USUARIO_NOME=tc4; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T13:38:07.753-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T13:38:07.753-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=403; USUARIO_NOME=(null); USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T13:50:01.627-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T13:50:01.627-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=404; USUARIO_NOME=tc5; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T13:50:52-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T13:50:52-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=405; USUARIO_NOME=tc6; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T13:51:29.56-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T13:51:29.56-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=406; USUARIO_NOME=bzjshd; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T13:56:13.733-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T13:56:13.733-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=407; USUARIO_NOME=gk; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T13:57:56.077-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T13:57:56.077-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=408; USUARIO_NOME=zbmz; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T14:00:05.36-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T14:00:05.36-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=409; USUARIO_NOME=yi; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T14:01:00.717-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T14:01:00.717-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=410; USUARIO_NOME=(null); USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T14:02:41.573-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T14:02:41.573-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=411; USUARIO_NOME=(null); USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T14:03:43.123-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T14:03:43.123-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=412; USUARIO_NOME=(null); USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T14:06:02.483-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T14:06:02.483-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=413; USUARIO_NOME=(null); USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T14:08:33.357-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T14:08:33.357-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=414; USUARIO_NOME=(null); USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T14:08:56.8-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T14:08:56.8-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=415; USUARIO_NOME=singe feliz; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T15:26:37.81-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-03T10:07:40.35-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=416; USUARIO_NOME=single triste; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T15:27:30.487-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T15:27:30.487-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=417; USUARIO_NOME=rrr; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T16:35:59.91-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T16:35:59.91-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=418; USUARIO_NOME=sss; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T16:36:19.717-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T16:36:19.717-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=419; USUARIO_NOME=qws; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T16:37:59.92-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T16:37:59.92-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=420; USUARIO_NOME=qwa; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=anyType{}; USUARIO_DATA_CADASTRO=2012-04-02T16:38:22.61-03:00; USUARIO_DATA_ATUALIZACAO=2012-04-02T16:42:27.02-03:00; USUARIO_ATIVO=A; }; Table=anyType{USUARIO_CODIGO=421; USUARIO_NOME=zxc; USUARIO_NUMERO_PARTICIPANTES=1; USUARIO_DESCRICAO=anyType{}; USUARIO_LATITUDE=0; USUARIO_LONGITUDE=0; USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL=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...

Comment: Could you put the "disorganized data"? And what type of object do you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet I extracted from my code:

```
int numOfCampuses = response.getPropertyCount();
for(int campusCtr=0; campusCtr<numOfCampuses;campusCtr++){
    SoapObject campus = (SoapObject)response.getProperty(campusCtr);

    String campusName = campus.getProperty("CampusName").toString();
    boolean isDefaultCampus = Boolean.parseBoolean(campus.getProperty("DefaultCampus").toString());
    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(campus.getProperty("Latitude").toString());
    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(campus.getProperty("Longitude").toString());

    campuses.add(new Campus(campusName, isDefaultCampus, latitude, longitude));
}
```